# Error in OauthCordova when test in device

Tags: ionic-framework, oauth, ionic3

I did an authentication using OauthCordova to enter Instagram. When I use the application in `Ionic DevApp`, authentication works. But when I try to run the application on the device (using `ionic cordova run android --device`) I get an error.

The function:

```
toLogin(event) {
        this.oauth.logInVia(this.instagram).then((success) => {
            this.localStorageProvider.setAccessToken(success);
            this.isLogged();
        }, (error) => {
            this.toast.create(
                {
                    message: 'Erro ao efetuar login. Tente novamente.',
                    position: 'botton',
                    duration: 5000
                }).present();

            console.log(JSON.stringify(error, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error)));
            console.log((error));
        });;
    }
```

Output:

```
console.log: {"stack":"Error: The Apache Cordova InAppBrowser plugin was not found and is required\n at
            ensureEnvIsValid (http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/vendor.js:134774:15)\n at
            http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/vendor.js:134792:17\n at new t
            (http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20886)\n at OauthCordova.openDialog
            (http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/vendor.js:134790:16)\n at OauthCordova.Oauth.logInVia
            (http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/vendor.js:82756:21)\n at LoginPage.webpackJsonp.107.LoginPage.toLogin
            (http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/main.js:104:20)\n at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
            (ng:///LoginPageModule/LoginPage.ngfactory.js:23:31)\n at handleEvent
            (http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/vendor.js:12380:138)\n at callWithDebugContext
            (http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/vendor.js:13850:42)\n at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent]
            (http://192.168.1.7:8100/build/vendor.js:13438:12)","message":"The Apache Cordova InAppBrowser plugin was
            not found and is required","__zone_symbol__currentTask":{}}

console.log:
            {"__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}
```

Comment: As per your log you have to install in app browser plugin. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Comment: Is it! Thank you.